# How to show two Poisson processes are independent

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I want to show that two Poisson processes $X$ and $Y$ are independent. So far, I have been able to prove that $X_{t}$ and $Y_{t}$ are independent for each time $t$. Somehow, one can deduce from this that for $s,t \geq 0$, $X_{s}$ and $Y_{t}$ are independent. Once I have established this, I can then conclude that the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $X$ and $Y$ are independent from which the independence of $X$ and $Y$ follows.
Can somebody please explain to me why you can deduce that the processes are independent at different times from the fact that they are independent at the same time? I have the feeling it is somehow related to the independent increments property of Poisson processes but I don't really know how.

Thanks!

Comment: Poisson Processes are memoryless, in the sense that if you condition on $X_s$ then $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $X_s$ for $t>s$. Try looking at $P(X_t,Y_s)$ with $t>s$ and condition on $X_s$.

Comment: Could you state the definition of $X$ and $Y$ (or is it too lengthy)?

Comment: @AlexR., somehow I am doing something wrong. I have tried multiple things but nothing really works. This is what I have at the moment (sorry for the change in notation): \begin{align}\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a,X_{t}^{b}=b \mid X_{s}^{b}=c) 
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}=b\mid X_{s}^{b}=c)\\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c,X_{s}^{b}=c\mid X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c) \end{align}

Comment: @saz, they are pretty generic Poisson processes with rates $\lambda p$ and $\lambda (1-p)$ - for $p\in[0,1]$ - respectively. The whole question here is part of the proof that if I thin a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ into two Poisson processes (as above), then these processes are again Poisson and independent of one another.

Comment: @Linus Ah, that's quite helpful.

Comment: try multiplying both sides by $P(X_s^b=c) and integrating, to get rid of the conditional probability.

Comment: @AlexR., does this here work?
$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a,X_{t}^{b}=b, X_{s}^{b}=c)
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c)\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c,X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}=b,X_{s}^{b}=c)\end{align*}
Summing over all possible values of $c$ then yields the required result
\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a,X_{t}^{b}=b) &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}=b).
\end{align*}$

Comment: \mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a,X_{t}^{b}=b, X_{s}^{b}=c)
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c)\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c,X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}=b,X_{s}^{b}=c)

Comment: Sorry guys, I can neither delete nor edit the comments above, somehow my code didn't work. Can an admin please delete the gibberish? Thanks!

Comment: Here is another try: \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a,X_{t}^{b}=b, X_{s}^{b}=c)
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c)\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c,X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}=b,X_{s}^{b}=c)

Comment: @AlexR., ok, I multiplied on both sides as you said and got this:\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a,X_{t}^{b}=b, X_{s}^{b}=c)
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c)\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}-X_{s}^{b}=b-c,X_{s}^{b}=c) \\
   &=\mathbb{P}(X_{s}^{a}=a)\mathbb{P}(X_{t}^{b}=b,X_{s}^{b}=c) \end{align*} Summing over all the possible values of $c$ completes the result. --- Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s<t$ and denote by $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ the process which you would like to thin. Then, $Y_t-Y_s$ and $X_t-X_s$ are independent from $\mathcal{F}_s := \sigma(W_r; r \leq s)$. Thus, by tower property,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \exp(\imath \, \xi \cdot X_s + \imath \, \eta \cdot Y_t) &= \mathbb{E} \bigg[ e^{\imath \, \eta \cdot Y_s+\imath \, \xi \cdot X_s} \cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left( e^{\imath \, \eta \cdot (Y_t-Y_s)} \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right)}_{\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \eta \cdot (Y_t-Y_s)}} \bigg] \\ &= \underbrace{\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \eta \cdot (Y_t-Y_s)} \cdot \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \eta \cdot Y_s}}_{\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \eta \cdot Y_t}} \cdot \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \xi \cdot X_s}\end{align*}$$

This proves that $X_s$ and $Y_t$ are independent.